# Unable to implement POST method in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, post, postman

I am trying to implement a simple POST method, but unable to do so.

Tried several solutions mentioned in "stackoverflow", still getting error.

My Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/public")
public class PublicRestApiController {

@GetMapping("users")
public List<User> users(){
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping(path="/insert",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
 public User add(@RequestBody UserRequest account) {
    User response = new User(account.getUsername(),account.getPassword(),account.getRoles(), account.getPermissions());
    return response;
    }

}
```

UserRequest class

```
public class UserRequest {

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public int getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(int active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public String getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(String roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public String getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}
public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}
private String username;
private String password;
private int active;
private String roles = "";
private String permissions = "";

}
```

User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class User {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String PASSWORD;

@Column
private int ACTIVE;

@Column
private String ROLES = "";

@Column
private String PERMISSIONS = "";

public User(String username, String password, String roles, String permissions){
    this.username = username;
    this.PASSWORD = password;
    this.ROLES = roles;
    this.PERMISSIONS = permissions;
    this.ACTIVE = 1;
}

public User(){}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return PASSWORD;
}

public int getActive() {
    return ACTIVE;
}

public String getRoles() {
    return ROLES;
}

public String getPermissions() {
    return PERMISSIONS;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.PASSWORD = password;
}

public void setActive(int active) {
    this.ACTIVE = active;
}

public void setRoles(String roles) {
    this.ROLES = roles;
}

public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
    this.PERMISSIONS = permissions;
}
}
```

This error message is appearing.

```
2019-05-28 17:08:41.808  WARN 7712 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

GET methods are working fine within same controller, only getting error while trying to implement POST implement.

[Request screenshot through Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvVOH.png)

Security Config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/public/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/api/public/insert").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .and()
      .httpBasic();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"rc.bootsecurity"})
public class BootSecurityApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BootSecurityApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    // Enable SSL Trafic
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };

    // Add HTTP to HTTPS redirect
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpToHttpsRedirectConnector());

    return tomcat;
}

private Connector httpToHttpsRedirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8082);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
    }
}
```

Comment: The attached error is telling that Request method 'GET' not supported which is right. Because your controller is POST.... how do you make sure that GET method is working....

Comment: sometimes server cache will create these type of problems. Clear the server cache and restart your server. Also in postman check whether the headers are having content-type checked or not.

Comment: From the error message, it appears that the Postman request is being sent as a `GET` request in stead of a `POST`. This appears to be possible when a redirect happens, as seen [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/450) and [here](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-I-sent-a-POST-request-but-Postman-seems-to-be-sending-a-GET-request-). Please verify if you're using redirects somewhere or not.

Comment: Did you enable `Spring Security`? If so, you're possibly getting redirected to a "Access Denied" page.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes, I am redirecting from http -> https. What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Possible Solution 1:

1. Open Postman
2. Go to Settings using File Section
3. Turn off Automatically follow redirects

[image]

---

> Possible Solution 2:

Add an `extra / (trailing slash) to your endPoint`
change `api/public/insert` to `api/public/insert/`

---

What Postman Support says about **I sent a POST request, but Postman seems to be sending a GET request.**

> This is mostly due to a server-side redirect. If Postman receives a
>   301 or 302 response code, it will automatically follow the redirect.
>   Similar to the behaviour in browsers, the original request method will
>   NOT be preserved, and the redirected request will be made with a GET
>   method. If you want to disable the auto-follow redirect behaviour, or
>   if you have other questions regarding this, please review the relevant
>   documentation on redirects

[Postman Support](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-I-sent-a-POST-request-but-Postman-seems-to-be-sending-a-GET-request-) [Interceptor extension](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension/) [Git Issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/450)

---

UPDATE:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/public/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/public/insert").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my security class and application class in the question. Get method is working fine. POST is not.I have tried both of your solutions. Not getting Forbidden error.

Comment: @SrijibSen so now your post request is sent as a POST instead of GET and now you are getting 403 Forbidden correct me if I am wrong and which solution worked for you

Comment: now it is working. I have changed the settings of Postman and updated code according to your advise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome @SrijibSen

Comment: Can you help me another problem regarding the same code??

Comment: @SrijibSen I will try to solve it, you can update the question here or can ask a new question as per your need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357766/unable-to-get-proper-get-response this is the new problem @Patel Romil