# Unable to get proper GET response

Tags: spring-boot, get

I am trying to implement a GET and a POST method in spring-boot. While calling GET method not getting proper response.

My Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/public")
public class PublicRestApiController {

@GetMapping("users")
public List<User> users(){
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping(path="/save")
@ResponseBody public User insertusers( @RequestBody UserRequest requestUser){
    User user = new User(requestUser.getUsername(),passwordEncoder.encode(requestUser.getPassword()),requestUser.getRoles(),requestUser.getPermissions());
    try { 
        user = this.userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
    catch(Error e) {
        return user;
    }
}

}
```

UserRequest class

```
public class UserRequest {

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public int getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(int active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public String getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(String roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public String getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}
public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}
private String username;
private String password;
private int active;
private String roles = "";
private String permissions = "";

}
```

User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class User {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String PASSWORD;

@Column
private int ACTIVE;

@Column
private String ROLES = "";

@Column
private String PERMISSIONS = "";

public User(String username, String password, String roles, String permissions){
    this.username = username;
    this.PASSWORD = password;
    this.ROLES = roles;
    this.PERMISSIONS = permissions;
    this.ACTIVE = 1;
}

public User(){}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return PASSWORD;
}

public int getActive() {
    return ACTIVE;
}

public String getRoles() {
    return ROLES;
}

public String getPermissions() {
    return PERMISSIONS;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.PASSWORD = password;
}

public void setActive(int active) {
    this.ACTIVE = active;
}

public void setRoles(String roles) {
    this.ROLES = roles;
}

public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
    this.PERMISSIONS = permissions;
}
}
```

UserRepository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

POST method is working fine, but while calling GET method, id field is coming default value 0.Not fetching proper ID values. And also while running server, if I call POST method, it is inserting data in database, but that newly inserted data is not getting fetched by GET method.Only those data are getting fetched, which I have already inserted in the database.

[This is the data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLZrJ.jpg)

[This is the response which I am getting form GET method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yrM.jpg)

Comment: try `private Long id;` instead of `private int id;`.  On your repo, you've declared that your ID is a Long: `public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{`. But your entity is using `int`. Unsure what the effects of that would be, but looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your USER class has Primary key with Type `int` and in your Repository, you have extended
USER class with long which should be Integer as below

**Repository:**

```
 @Repository
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

 }
```

---

UPDATE:

```
 @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

         @GetMapping("users")
         public List<User> users(){
              return userRepository.getAllUsers();
         }
```

Repository:

```
 @Repository
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
      @Query(value="select * from USER_DETAILS",nativeQuery=true)
      List<User> getAllUsers();
 }
```

import `@Query` from `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;`

---

UPDATE2:
Idel way of project structure is to have different packages according to class behavior.

- Controller
- Service
- Repository
- Models or Entity
- DTOs, DAOs
- Security, Config etc as per the requirnments

---

```
     //Controller
     @yourMapping
     public returnType method1()
     {
         myService.performBusinessLoginonMethod1(...) //if you are using services
         myReposiroty.DBOpertaion(...) //as per above case
     }

     //Service: myService
     returnType  performBusinessLoginonMethod1(...) 
     {
         myRepository.DBOpertaion(...)
     }

     //Repository: myRepository     
     @Modifying // import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
     @Query(...)
     returnType DBOpertaion(...)
```

Comment: Still getting zero only as ID.

Comment: @SrijibSen can you add the response you are getting and actual data in the database

Comment: Added the details.

Comment: Hello @SrijibSen can you try with a manual query in a repository and share the response and have you changed long to Integer in a repository

Comment: Yes, I have changed Long to integer. And I don't know how to use manual query. I have just started exploring spring-boot.

Comment: @SrijibSen please refer the update and let me know the outcome

Comment: Yes, now it is working. But if I have to write another method with another manual query, in that case how I can write and map those against methods?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning reponse properly. Try this.

```
    @GetMapping("users")
public ResponseEntity<List<Article>> users(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Article>>(this.userRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: POST method is working fine. Data is getting stored in database. But after calling POST if I call GEt, the newly inserted data is not getting fetched.

Comment: Not possible, you are not inserting data anywhere. Check your add method in controller.